# How can I add a new column in a dataframe for each iteration with a new name (using for)? Python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to make a calculation for each item in a list. Then, I want to add these new values to a column in a dataframe. The name of the column should be: name_item
This is what I have so far:

```
list_thr = [0.1, 0.5]


for n in list_thr:
    y_scores = (best_classifier.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]>=n).astype(int) 
    probs_score = best_classifier.predict_proba(X_test)

    df_final['preds'] = y_scores #df_final is the dataframe I want to put the columns
```

However, if I keep it, the column 'preds' will be replaced in each iteraction.
What I want is 1 column for each iteraction and with "n" in the name, such as:

df_final:

```
preds_0.1   preds_0.5
1           1
0           0
0           1
0           0
1           1
```

How can I change my loop to get that?

Answer (score 3):

You can add the `n` when iterating as part of the column name when you define it. This will create a new column with the name `preds` and the suffix `n` for each loop:

```
for n in list_thr:
    y_scores = (best_classifier.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]>=n).astype(int) 
    probs_score = best_classifier.predict_proba(X_test)

    df_final['preds'+str(n)] = y_scores
```